# iOS - Issue When Consuming API - dispatch_async

Tags: ios, objective-c, dispatch-async

I was trying to get a basic prototype of an API working.  I have the web service setup and now I'm trying to have an iOS app request the data and display it in a table.  It's pretty basic, however, random parts of the data are displaying as `null` in the table and I haven't been able to find a common thread.

But basically, I make a call to this API, I parse the data, i use a `StopCollection` class to `createItem` (of type `StopItem`) and add it to an `NSMutableArray` in `StopCollection`.  And then in the `MainTableViewController`, I use that array as a data source.

The data comes in correctly from the API.  I'm able to add it the `NSMutableArray` just fine.  However, it seems that in the `MainTableViewController`, once I get to the following line, I no longer have access to the same data in the array and bunch of the values are `null`:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

Here's what I'm working with:

**MainTableViewController.m**

```
#import "MainTableViewController.h"
#import "StopCollection.h"
#import "StopItem.h"

@interface MainTableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLSession *session;

@end

@implementation MainTableViewController

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    if (self) {
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        _session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config
                                                 delegate:nil
                                            delegateQueue:nil];
        [self fetchFeed];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)fetchFeed
{
    NSString *requestString = @"http://nexttrain.dev/station?include=stopTime";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask =
    [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                    completionHandler:
                        ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                            NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                                           options:0
                                                                                             error:nil];
                                for(NSDictionary *stop in jsonObject[@"data"])
                                {
                                    for (NSDictionary *stopTime in stop[@"stopTime"][@"data"]) {

                                    [[StopCollection sharedStore] createItem:stop[@"station"]
                                                                   withRoute:stopTime[@"route"]
                                                                withHeadsign:stopTime[@"trip"]
                                                             withArrivalTime:stopTime[@"arrival_time"]];
                                    NSLog(@"%@", stop[@"station"]);
                                    }
                                }

                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                                });
                            }];

    [dataTask resume];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]
           forCellReuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[StopCollection sharedStore] stops] count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"
                                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSArray *allStops = [[StopCollection sharedStore] stops];
    StopItem *stop = allStops[indexPath.row];

    NSString *formattedText =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@ - %@", stop.station, stop.route, stop.arrivalTime];
    cell.textLabel.text = formattedText;

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];

    return cell;
}
```

**StopCollection.m**

```
#import "StopCollection.h"
#import "StopItem.h"

@interface StopCollection()

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *privateStops;

@end

@implementation StopCollection

// Override Accessor for Stops, and return from privateStops.
- (NSArray *)stops
{
    return [self.privateStops copy];
}

// Singleton Access to Object.
+ (instancetype)sharedStore
{
    // Static will be Strong and will remain.
    static StopCollection *sharedStore;
    // Create initial instance.
    if (!sharedStore) {
        sharedStore = [[self alloc] initPrivate];
    }
    // Return instance if exists.
    return sharedStore;
}

// Make defualt init inaccessible.
- (instancetype)init
{
    // Throw Exception if accesssed.
    [NSException raise:@"Singleton"
                format:@"Use + (instancetype)sharedStore"];
    return nil;
}

// Private initializer will call Super init.
- (instancetype)initPrivate
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _privateStops = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)createItem:(NSString *)station withRoute:(NSString *)route withHeadsign:(NSString *)headsign withArrivalTime:(NSString *)arrivalTime
{    
    StopItem *stop = [[StopItem alloc] initWithStation:station
                                                lattitude:22
                                                longitude:56
                                                    route:route
                                            tripHeadsign:headsign
                                           arrivalTime];

    [self.privateStops addObject:stop];
}



@end
```

**StopCollection.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface StopCollection : NSObject

+ (instancetype)sharedStore;
@property(nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSArray *stops;
- (void)createItem:(NSString *)station
         withRoute:(NSString *)route
      withHeadsign:(NSString *)headsign
   withArrivalTime:(NSString *)arrivalTime;

@end
```

**StopItem.m**

```
#import "StopItem.h"

@implementation StopItem

- (instancetype)initWithStation:(NSString *)station lattitude:(NSInteger)lattitude longitude:(NSInteger)longitude route:(NSString *)route tripHeadsign:(NSString *)headsign arrivalTime:(NSString *)arrivalTime
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _station = station;
        _lattitude = lattitude;
        _longitude = longitude;
        _route = route;
        _tripHeadsign = headsign;
        _arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
    }

    return self;
}

- (instancetype)init {

    return [self initWithStation:@"Hey" lattitude:0 longitude:0 route:@"" tripHeadsign:@"" arrivalTime:[[NSString alloc] init]];
}

@end
```

**StopItem.h**

```
@interface StopItem : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString    *station;
@property (nonatomic)       NSInteger   lattitude;
@property (nonatomic)       NSInteger   longitude;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString    *route;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString    *tripHeadsign;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString    *arrivalTime;

- (instancetype)initWithStation:(NSString *)station
                      lattitude:(NSInteger)lattitude
                      longitude:(NSInteger)longitude
                          route:(NSString *)route
                   tripHeadsign:(NSString *)headsign
                    arrivalTime:(NSString *)arrivalTime;

@end
```

And here's the JSON data set I'm working with:

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "station":"2 Av",
         "lattitude":"40.723402",
         "longitude":"-73.989938",
         "stopTime":{  
            "data":[  
               {  
                  "arrival_time":"02:40:30",
                  "trip":"JAMAICA - 179 ST",
                  "route":"some longer word with a -"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {  
         "station":"2 Av",
         "lattitude":"40.723402",
         "longitude":"-73.989938",
         "stopTime":{  
            "data":[  
               {  
                  "arrival_time":"00:54:00",
                  "trip":"CONEY ISLAND - STILLWELL AV",
                  "route":"some longer word with a -"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {  
         "station":"Delancey St",
         "lattitude":"40.718611",
         "longitude":"-73.988114",
         "stopTime":{  
            "data":[  
               {  
                  "arrival_time":"02:39:00",
                  "trip":"JAMAICA - 179 ST",
                  "route":"some longer word with a -"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {  
         "station":"Delancey St",
         "lattitude":"40.718611",
         "longitude":"-73.988114",
         "stopTime":{  
            "data":[  
               {  
                  "arrival_time":"00:55:30",
                  "trip":"CONEY ISLAND - STILLWELL AV",
                  "route":"some longer word with a -"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {  
         "station":"Essex St",
         "lattitude":"40.718315",
         "longitude":"-73.987437",
         "stopTime":{  
            "data":[  
               {  
                  "arrival_time":"01:23:30",
                  "trip":"JAMAICA CENTER - PARSONS/ARCHER",
                  "route":"some longer word with a -"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {  
         "station":"Essex St",
         "lattitude":"40.718315",
         "longitude":"-73.987437",
         "stopTime":{  
            "data":[  
               {  
                  "arrival_time":"00:52:30",
                  "trip":"BROAD ST",
                  "route":"some longer word with a -"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {  
         "station":"Bowery",
         "lattitude":"40.72028",
         "longitude":"-73.993915",
         "stopTime":{  
            "data":[  
               {  
                  "arrival_time":"01:22:00",
                  "trip":"JAMAICA CENTER - PARSONS/ARCHER",
                  "route":"some longer word with a -"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {  
         "station":"Bowery",
         "lattitude":"40.72028",
         "longitude":"-73.993915",
         "stopTime":{  
            "data":[  
               {  
                  "arrival_time":"00:54:00",
                  "trip":"BROAD ST",
                  "route":"some longer word with a -"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: First thing to note, are you sure you are not receiving `NSNull`s in json? Second, what about properties of `StopItem`, are they `strong`, `weak`, `copy` or whatsoever? What about keys you are using for json data? If possible, you'd better post some piece of json.

Comment: @FahriAzimov Added the headers files and JSON.  the JSON is definitely valid, with no null values.  Like I said, within the iOS app, I'm able to successfully dump all the data once I receive it from the API, and am able to store in the `StopItem` model successfully, and in the collection Array.  But somewhere around the that `dispatch_async` line, things seem to change, though I'm not entirely sure how thats possible.  I do know that by the time I get the the data being parsed by the `TableViewController` delegate methods (for each row), there are null values all of a sudden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not related to `dispatch`. It's because you have `weak` properties, which get nilled whenever possible, i.e. when there is no reference holding them. Change `weak` to `strong` or `copy` in your `StopItem` model, and everything will work.

Comment: Hm interesting. How come only some of the values don't display in the table then?  In fact, certain properties display in some rows, but are null in others. If it were a question of strong vs weak, wouldn't they all not display?  Will give that a try regardless though!

Comment: Maybe, some of them get displayed because they are still referenced somewhere else.

Comment: Yep, you're right! Changed them to strong and now they display properly. Thanks!